# Feed expect with some variables

Tags: bash, expect

I would like to use expect with cryptsetup. It could be whatever program instead of cryptsetup. I feed cryptsetup with a device, a virtual device name and a password.

```
#!/bin/bash 

read -p "Device: `echo $'\n> '`" DEV
read -p "Virtual Device: `echo $'\n> '`" VIRTUAL
read -p "Password: `echo $'\n> '`" PSWD

expect -c exec /sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/$DEV $VIRTUAL
expect "Enter passphrase for /dev/sdc1:"
send $PSWD
```

I also tried with 'spawn' but it does not work either.
any idea is more than welcome! thanx folks.

Answer (score 1):

You can overcome the *expect* dependency by substituting the last three lines of codes with the following :

```
echo $PSWD | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/$DEV $VIRTUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you question and comments, you need something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

read -p "Device: `echo $'\n> '`" DEV
read -p "Virtual Device: `echo $'\n> '`" VIRTUAL

/sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/$DEV $VIRTUAL

mount  /dev/mapper/$VIRTUAL /mnt/$DEV
```

cryptsetup will ask you password, you will enter it. After this mount will run. That's all. And you don't need expect and any variable to store password.